# Mozilla not working with svg stroke-dashoffset

Tags: html, css, svg, mozilla

It works well in Google Chrome, but in Mozilla Firefox my svg path suddenly appears!
What's wrong?

Body:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
             viewBox="0 0 390 170" enable-background="new 0 0 390 170" xml:space="preserve">
     <path id="ADM-A" class="ADM-SVG"
          d="M78.246,105.517c0,0-27.246-0.517-27.246-26.972c0-24.878,25.626-25.211,25.626-25.211S103,54,103,80.113c0,22.554,0,26.779,0,26.779"
     />
</svg>
```

Style:

```
.ADM-SVG {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #ffffff;
    stroke-width: 17;
    stroke-linecap: round;
    stroke-linejoin: round;
    stroke-miterlimit: 10;
    stroke-opacity: 1;
    stroke-dasharray: 220;
    stroke-dashoffset: 220;
    -webkit-transition-property: stroke-dashoffset;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 10s;
    -moz-transition-property: stroke-dashoffset;
    -moz-transition-duration: 10s;
    transition-property: stroke-dashoffset;
    transition-duration: 10s;
}
```

Script:

```
$("#ADM-A").css({ "stroke-dashoffset": 0 });
```

Comment: SVG does not support CSS transitions, Chrome should behave like Firefox according to spec. You'd need to use javascript to animate the stroke.

Comment: @Duopixel, I capture this from Chrome:  [`LINK`](http://www.mediafire.com/watch/p64y0d26w2dwe6z/SVG_Transition_in_Chrome.mp4)  . So, Chrome Doesn't behave like Firefox. You have better idea?

Comment: as I've said before, use javascript to animate `stroke-dashoffset`. This is an example with D3 http://bl.ocks.org/duopixel/4063326.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can animate svg with css, [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Diesel9Design/u9axm/1/) but I noticed that for chrome enter code here vs firefox they animate it differently.

The following works for firefox:

```
.logo-rect {
    fill: transparent; 
    stroke:#333;
    stroke-width:3px;
    stroke-dashoffset:-120;
    stroke-dasharray:360 360;
    opacity:1;
    transition: stroke-width 2s, stroke-dashoffset 2s, stroke-dasharray 2s, opacity 2s;
}
```

However for Chrome change the dataoffset to -360 and it will animate properly.