# SVG rect not showing up in firefox but works on chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, firefox, svg

I am drawing a simple two rectangle svg as follows:

```
<svg  width="72px" height="72px" viewBox="0 0 72 72" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <rect stroke-dashoffset="0" x="2.4px" y="2.4px"></rect>
          <rect ng-class="$ctrl.expiryClass"
          x="2.4px" y="2.4px"
          stroke-dasharray={{$ctrl.dashlength}}
          stroke-dashoffset={{$ctrl.offset}}></rect>
      </svg>
```

This works well in chrome and looks like this:

[image: Progress bar as svg rect]

However, the svg is not showing up in FireFox and I am only seeing the purple `2h` box. 
Any idea whats going on?

Comment: There some questions about the stroke-dashoffset not workin in firefox, like this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18298482/mozilla-not-working-with-svg-stroke-dashoffset

Comment: The rect has no width and height attributes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I expect you are setting the rectangle's `width` and `height` using CSS. Correct?

If so, that's an SVG 2 thing that currently only works in Chrome.  You'll need to use regular `width` and `height` attributes if you want this to be cross-browser compatible.

```
<rect stroke-dashoffset="0" x="2.4px" y="2.4px" width="100px" height="100px"/>
```